# Extended harmonic numbers definition converges uniformly

Tags: uniform-convergence, harmonic-numbers

I'm trying to prove the sum

$H_x :=\lim_{n \to \infty}   \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{1}{k} -\frac{1}{x+k} \right)$

converging uniformly at $x\neq -1, -2, ...$.

Using the weirstrass m-test i proved it for $x\geq0$, but have trouble proving it on the intervals $... \cup (-3,-2) \cup (-2,-1)$.

So far I got

$$\lvert \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{x+k}\rvert=\lvert \frac{x}{k(x+k)} \rvert= \frac{-x}{k\lvert(x+k)\rvert}$$

at which point I'm not sure how to manipulate the denominator.

Comment: Are you sure about uniform convergence? I do not think, that you can expect something like that, since if $x$ approaches e.g. $-1$, then the function will blow up. Hence I only expect local uniform convergence in $\mathbb{R}\setminus (-\mathbb{N})$. One more hint: Let $|x|\leq C$. Then there exists some $k_0=k_0(C)>0$ such that for all $k>k_0$ we have $x\geq -\frac{k}{2}$, which could help you in manipulating the denominator.

Comment: That's right.. hence i dont even know how to prove it for $x\in(-1,0)$. Does it mean the m-test wont work on these intervals?